# private key not found in azure deployment using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to to create azure Linux using terraform .
I am able to deploy the VM perfectly.
but when I am trying to install some package using remote exec  it get failed "Unable to read SSH key".
As I am trying the script from my window laptop using power shell.

What my concern is how to call my private key for installing  some packages inside connection block?

Comment: this is my code connection {
    host        = azurerm_public_ip.myterraformpublicip.id
    user        = "azureuser"
    type        = "ssh"
    private_key = "?"
    timeout     = "4m"
    agent       = false
  }



  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo apt-get update",
      "sudo apt-get install docker.io -y",
      "sudo apt install default-jdk",

    ]
  }

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to add the code, rather than adding it in comments, which are not really meant to include code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer using the below mention method
https://www.codewrecks.com/post/devops/terraform-hello-world